# error: expected unqualified id before }

Tags: c++

Can someone help me this compiling error:

> ```
> expected unqualified id before } at line3
> ```

```
class CHexApp{public:
 protected:
  void  {{AFX_VIRTUAL(CHexApp)
    virtual BOOL InitInstance();
     }}AFX_VIRTUAL

protected:
   void  {{AFX_MSG(CHexApp)
    }}AFX_MSG

    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP();

};
```

Comment: There's no `}` on line 3. Are you sure you copied the lines as they are in the original program?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you want to do, but according to [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12612/HexView-an-introductory-MFC-application) tutorial your code should look like:

```
class CHexApp : public CWinApp 
{
protected:
    //{{AFX_VIRTUAL(CHexApp)
    virtual BOOL InitInstance();
    //}}AFX_VIRTUAL

protected:
    //}}AFX_MSG(CHexApp)
    //}}AFX_MSG

    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
};
```